# Would gravity be stronger or weaker on different sides of a dual planet?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, planets, gravity

If you had two similar sized planets that were tidally locked to each other, would gravity change depending on whether you were closer to the sister-world?  Assuming they were quite close.

Comment: related:  https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/97832/which-astronomical-or-cosmological-event-would-explain-periodical-low-grav-effec/97908#97908

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which astronomical or cosmological event would explain periodical low-grav-effect on earth-like planet?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/97832/which-astronomical-or-cosmological-event-would-explain-periodical-low-grav-effec)

Comment: And please remember, we don't use [tag:reality-check] and [tag@science-based] [tags together](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2004/does-hard-science-imply-science-based-imply-reality-check).

Comment: Proposed q is not a dublicate, from that q 20-30% gravity change in 15 month - for sure is not  this q case

Comment: Feel that your question is answered already - Yes, gravity changes for double planets depending upon where in the orbit they are. Perhaps you can expand on this with details about the world in your story, and ask about other relevant details - eg. planet A weighs X, planet B weighs Y, the gravity is about 30% at the points at which they are closer, can my dwarves perform slam dunks when the two planets are closest?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Tidal effects will reduce the net surface gravity along the line between the planets, and increase it along the perpendicular planes passing through the centers of each world. You end up with the highest gravity at each planet's poles (just as it would be with an isolated planet), middle-strength at the east and west "poles" (intersection of the equator and visible terminator line), and least at the inner and outer poles.

The complete gravity map is kinda complicated, but the same tidal forces will end up distorting each planet into a squashed egg shape, following the shape of a Roche lobe. The farther apart they are, the less noticeable this distortion will be, and the less gravity will vary across their surfaces.